# Dropbox always updates its dameon at startup

Tags: 20.04, dropbox

I've upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, and the Dropbox client always asks to update its proprietary daemon. After that, there is two Dropbox icon in the system tray.

The only solution I've found on the net is to disable the `-i` parameter in `dropbox start -i` but I'm concerned about Dropbox not going to update anymore.

Can anyone help?

Edit: the version of Dropbox stays at v108.4.453 even after update and reboot. It doesn't really update. It also puts back the `-i` parameter which results in the whole issue happening again and again.

Comment: What is your current Dropbox version?

Comment: It's v108.4.453